# Access AWS EFS from two different VPC's in same account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, amazon-vpc, amazon-efs

I have an EFS file system. I have created two mounts one for `us-east-1a` and another for `us-east-1b` and both are in the same VPC. Now I have a requirement to add a mount point and it's in a different VPC but in the same account. When I try to create the mount target I get the below error

```
aws efs create-mount-target --file-system-id fs-abcdef  --subnet-id subnet-156fd195808k8l --security-groups sg-99b88u518a368dp

An error occurred (MountTargetConflict) when calling the CreateMountTarget operation: requested subnet for new mount target is not in the same VPC as existing mount targets
```

is there a way I can use the EFS in two different VPCs?

Comment: Is there connectivity between the 2 VPCs (vpc peering or TGW)?

Comment: @OARP Yes, there is a vpc peering between two VPCs

Answer (score 0):

VPC peering OR Transit Gateway is enough in order for NFS client from different VPC to connect to EFS in separate VPC.

[image]

Only one mount target for a certain EFS is needed per AZ. The error shows that you already have mount target for the specific EFS.

[image]

To connect your NFS client you can follow the AWS provide [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/efs-different-vpc.html)